# Response.Redirect causing visual studio to stop execution

Tags: visual-studio, exception

When Response.Redirect is called it throws a System.Threading.ThreadAbortException.  I am perfectly fine with this as the alternative is way too much of my code is run on an invalid page.

My problem is Visual Studio is breaking when I hit this line, and telling me "Exception User-Unhandled".  I know it's not handled by my code. It shouldn't need to be.  The IIS server will be fine eating the exception and redirecting the end user.  How do I get Visual Studio to shut up about it?

Things I have tried that didn't work:

1. Open the exception settings in the window that pops up and the "break when this exception type is user-unhandled" check mark is NOT checked.
2. Clicked on "Edit Conditions" and the first drop down says "Module Name" the 2nd drop down says "Not Equals" and the text box is empty, so there isn't any condition.
3. I clicked "Open Exception Settings" and a new window pops up with tons of types of exceptions.  I searched for ThreadAbortException and saw it wasn't checked.

   1. I tried checking and unchecking it
   2. I tried right clicking and clicking "Continue When Unhandled in User Code"
   3. I clicked the - icon to delete the exception from the list.

None of these stopped Visual Studio from breaking when the exception is thrown.

The really weird thing is I have a different project that also uses Response.Redirect and it's fine.  The exception is thrown so I can catch it if I want, but if I don't catch it, Visual Studio keeps quite about it and lets me continue onto the next page.  So far I haven't found what's different between the 2 projects, (they are in different solutions though so it might be at that level.)

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect works fine in the same project when we're in a WebForm extending System.Web.UI.Page.

Where it isn't working is in the Global.asax in the Application_PostAcquireRequestState() function. We've got the class called MvcApplication rather than Global but it's still extending System.Web.HttpApplication.

I'm not sure if it's an artifact of a partial MVC implementation or if it's because I'm doing a redirect at the earliest part of the code I could find that a session exists, rather than in a page.

We do have 1 MVC form in the project and use the MVC method of url-rewriting, (but most of the project is built in WebForms.)

For now I've used the following system to get around it as this does seem to skip the page rendering code, but I don't like allowing execution to continue after a redirect.

```
Response.Redirect(url, false);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```